# split in xslt 1.0 with the delimiter &

Tags: xslt, split, xslt-1.0

Hello I have the tag below with & separated and I need to get each separate field in different tags to write later in separate fields in database, anyone with any examples in xslt 1.0?

```
<StatusMsg>
transfer-encoding=chunked&Server=nginx%2F1.13.12&MeusPedidosURL=http%3A%2F%2Fintegracao.meuspedidos.com.br%2Fapi%2Fv1%2Fclientes4118343%2F&Connection=keep-alive&MEUSPEDIDOS_QTDE_TOTAL_REGISTROS=0&Vary=Authorization%2C+Cookie&MeusPedidosID=4118343&Date=Tue%2C+31+Dec+2019+22%3A16%3A46+GMT&Content-Type=text%2Fplain
</StatusMsg>
```

Example of what I need ...

```
<MeusPedidosID>4118343</MeusPedidosID>
<MeusPedidosURL>http%3A%2F%2Fintegracao.meuspedidos.com.br%2Fapi%2Fv1%2Fclientes4118343%2F</MeusPedidosURL>
```

Comment: That input with an unescaped ampersand doesn't even seem to be well-formed XML to be fed to an XML parser.  As for XSLT 1 and splitting strings, find out which XSLT 1 processor you use and whether it supports an EXSLT extension or calling into the host language to use its hopefully better string function support.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a **well-formed** input such as:

**XML**

```
<StatusMsg>transfer-encoding=chunked&amp;Server=nginx%2F1.13.12&amp;MeusPedidosURL=http%3A%2F%2Fintegracao.meuspedidos.com.br%2Fapi%2Fv1%2Fclientes4118343%2F&amp;Connection=keep-alive&amp;MEUSPEDIDOS_QTDE_TOTAL_REGISTROS=0&amp;Vary=Authorization%2C+Cookie&amp;MeusPedidosID=4118343&amp;Date=Tue%2C+31+Dec+2019+22%3A16%3A46+GMT&amp;Content-Type=text%2Fplain</StatusMsg>
```

you can use the `substring-before()` and `substring-after()` functions to extract the wanted values - for example, the following stylesheet:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:variable name="statusMsg" select="concat(StatusMsg, '&amp;')" />
    <output>
        <MeusPedidosID>
            <xsl:value-of select="substring-before(substring-after($statusMsg, 'MeusPedidosID='), '&amp;')"/>
        </MeusPedidosID>
        <MeusPedidosURL>
            <xsl:value-of select="substring-before(substring-after($statusMsg, 'MeusPedidosURL='), '&amp;')"/>
        </MeusPedidosURL>
    </output>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

will produce:

**Result**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<output>
  <MeusPedidosID>4118343</MeusPedidosID>
  <MeusPedidosURL>http%3A%2F%2Fintegracao.meuspedidos.com.br%2Fapi%2Fv1%2Fclientes4118343%2F</MeusPedidosURL>
</output>
```

---

If you want to extract **all** the fields encoded in the given string, you can use:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
    <output>
        <xsl:call-template name="split">
            <xsl:with-param name="string" select="concat(StatusMsg, '&amp;')"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
    </output>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="split">
    <xsl:param name="string"/>
    <xsl:if test="contains($string, '=')">
        <xsl:element name="{substring-before($string, '=')}">
            <xsl:value-of select="substring-before(substring-after($string, '='), '&amp;')" />
        </xsl:element>
        <!-- recursive call -->
        <xsl:call-template name="split">
            <xsl:with-param name="string" select="substring-after($string, '&amp;')" />
        </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

to get:

**Result**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<output>
  <transfer-encoding>chunked</transfer-encoding>
  <Server>nginx%2F1.13.12</Server>
  <MeusPedidosURL>http%3A%2F%2Fintegracao.meuspedidos.com.br%2Fapi%2Fv1%2Fclientes4118343%2F</MeusPedidosURL>
  <Connection>keep-alive</Connection>
  <MEUSPEDIDOS_QTDE_TOTAL_REGISTROS>0</MEUSPEDIDOS_QTDE_TOTAL_REGISTROS>
  <Vary>Authorization%2C+Cookie</Vary>
  <MeusPedidosID>4118343</MeusPedidosID>
  <Date>Tue%2C+31+Dec+2019+22%3A16%3A46+GMT</Date>
  <Content-Type>text%2Fplain</Content-Type>
</output>
```

Comment: Nice..
It worked...
Thank you very much.
I was already creating a workaround in C# language, but I'm glad your script worked